# What software can visualize HTML page tags in a tree?

Tags: web-development, html, data-visualization, html-editor

What software can display HTML document tags in a tree view?

[XML Schema editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_editors) can visualize xml document as a tree, but what software can visualize html document as a tree? [Horizontal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure#Classical_node-link_diagrams) and vertical tree visualization

**Visualize html nodes like this..**

[image]

**..or visualize like this**

[image: enter image description here2]

Comment: google chrome 'inspect' feature (developer console) let you browse into html source tree.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993554/view-html-source-in-tree-view

Answer (score 0):

I am reminded of [Kompozer](http://kompozer.sourceforge.net/). It is free, and open source, although it doesn't look like it has been updated for a few years.

This basic HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
      <h1> header 1</h1>
      <h2> header 1</h2>
      <span>
         <p>para 1</p>
         <p>para 2</p>
      </span>
   </div>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Is displayed in tag view as

[image]

Try it with something more complex and see how you like it.

Answer (score 0):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) editor is free, open source. It has code-tree for lot of "lexers", also for HTML and XML. Example look with short HTML:

[image: CudaText with HTML]

In the plugins (Plugins / Addon Manager / Install) you will find "treehelper: HTML_XML" which is more advanced version of HTML code-tree. More tags and more detailed look.

[image: treehelper for HTML]

Comment: Are you involved with the creation of this software? If so, please disclose your affiliation. Undisclosed affiliation recommendations like this where there is a suspicion of you working for the company may be marked as spam.